# Is it faster to set a bool value directly, or won't this save any time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

Is the second method faster than the first?

```
-(void)test:(BOOL)value
{
    if(value)
    {
        /*...*/
        [self otherMethod:value];
        /*...*/    
    }
    else
    {
        /*...*/
        [self otherMethod:value];
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

_

```
-(void)test:(BOOL)value
{
    if(value)
    {
        /*...*/
        [self otherMethod:YES]; 
        /*...*/   
    }
    else
    {
        /*...*/
        [self otherMethod:NO]; 
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

As I've already established that `value` indeed is `YES`, will it save any time directly setting `YES` rather than `value`? Will a read-operation on `value` take more time than "reading" `YES`?
(Given that some action will replace the commented parts, or else I could've dropped the if's)

Comment: In theory, the second methods has a chance of being faster. The compiler is fairly likely to optimize the first into the second, though. But **most importantly** the difference is so trivial that it won't matter at all. The cost of coming up with the argument for the `-otherMethod:` call is swamped by the cost of actually calling `-otherMethod:` by several orders of magnitude, not to mention everything else the method is likely to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)test:(BOOL)value {

    self.someVariable = value;

    if (self.someVariable) {



    } else {



    }
}
```

Also, only use YES and NO in objective c.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That is indeed fastest. However, the question remains unanswered. I completely agree that your solution is best, now I'm simply wondering if the 'read-operation' on `value` is slower than a simple `YES`/`NO`. And yes, I'm always using YES/NO in Objective-C, but I was originally trying to make this question easier to understand for people with other languages. I failed at that, though.

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure, but if `value` is set to `YES` then they are the same thing. `value` is already determined when you call the method (`[self test:YES];`)

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking this question. It's already determined, but I'm wondering if it takes more time to actually **access** the boolean value of `value` than to simply type YES/NO. I imagine it is. When writing `BOOL f = value;`, then we must first read the boolean inside `value`, then write it to `f`. I'm wondering if it takes more time to read what's stored in `value` rather than to read `YES`. I've updated the question to better reflect this.

Comment: [This is the header file that defines `BOOL`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h) and it says that `YES` = 1 and `NO` = 0, so even when writing `YES` it still has to read that `BOOL` just as it has to read `value`